# Trouble with array list

Tags: java, arrays

In the class WordPair() the method remove() is supposed to take in an array and split the strings inside of it and then add those string to two different array lists. wordListB works correctly and the array gets filled fine. Also when I a system print inside of this method it prints out wordListC correctly as well. The problem I am having it when the getWord method is called in the wordSelection method of the JlistFromFile class to retrieve a string from worldListC at a specific index, At this point the array prints out empty. I set up a test in the main and the class itself is working how its supposed to. I can't figure out what is making arrayListC to become cleared out.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.io.*;

/* Simple example of using the contents of a file to populate a JList
 * 
 * @author Jill Courte
 */

public class JListFromFile extends JFrame {

  private TextField wordA;
  private TextField wordB;
  private JButton openButton;
  private JButton newButton;
  private JButton addButton;
  private JButton deleteButton;
  private JButton saveButton;
  private TextField output;
  private JList listFromFile;
  private JPanel listPanel;
  private JPanel textPanel;
  private JPanel inputPanel;
  private JPanel buttonsPanel;
  private SimpleWordList dataSource;
  private WordPair wordPair;
  public JListFromFile ()
  {
    // create the object to provide the data
    dataSource = new SimpleWordList();
    wordPair = new WordPair();
    // use a border layout for the main window
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(20, 20));

    buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    openButton = new JButton("Open");
    newButton = new JButton("New");
    addButton = new JButton("Add");
    deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
    saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    addButton.setEnabled( false ); 
    deleteButton.setEnabled( false );
    saveButton.setEnabled( false );
    buttonsPanel.add(openButton);
    buttonsPanel.add(newButton);
    buttonsPanel.add(addButton);
    buttonsPanel.add(deleteButton);
    buttonsPanel.add(saveButton);

    //add the button listeners
    openButton.addActionListener(new OpenButtonListener());
    addButton.addActionListener(new AddButtonListener());

    add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // create the panel to hold the list
    listPanel = new JPanel();

    // create your JList
    listFromFile = new JList();
    listFromFile.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    listFromFile.setSelectedIndex(0);

    //add the list selection listener
   listFromFile.addListSelectionListener(new WordSelection());

    //add the translation text box 
    textPanel = new JPanel();
    output = new TextField();
    output.setEditable(false);
    output.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));
    textPanel.add(output);

    // add scroll bars to list 
    JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(listFromFile);
    listScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 200));

    //add user input textfield 
    wordA = new TextField ("Word to Add");
    wordB = new TextField ("Translated word");
    wordA.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));
    wordB.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));
    wordA.setEnabled(false);
    wordB.setEnabled(false);

    //create panel to hold input textfield
    inputPanel = new JPanel();
    inputPanel.add(wordA);
    inputPanel.add(wordB);

    //add the list (via the scroll pane) to the panel
    listPanel.add(listScrollPane);

    //add the panels to the frame
    add(listPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
  }


  private File findFile ()
  { 
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

    // Start in current directory
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
    int status = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);      

    if (status != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No File Selected");
      throw new NoFileChoosenException();
    }
    else
    {    
      File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

      System.out.println(file.getName());      
      System.out.println(file.getPath());


      return file;
    }
  }


  private class OpenButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {

      listFromFile.setListData(new Object[0]);

      File file = null;

      try
      {
        file = findFile();

        //tell the data source what file to use
        dataSource.createList(file);

        //JList needs an array of strings, retrieve it from the data source
        String [] data = dataSource.getData();

        //data = dataSource.insertion(data);
        //data = wordPair.remove(data);
        if (data != null)
        listFromFile.setListData(data);

      }
      catch (Exception e)
      { 
      }
      addButton.setEnabled(true); 
      deleteButton.setEnabled(true);
      saveButton.setEnabled(true);
      wordA.setEnabled(false);
      wordB.setEnabled(false);
    }
  }

  private class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {


      wordA.setEnabled(true);
      wordB.setEnabled(true);

      String inputStringA = wordA.getText();
      String inputStringB = wordB.getText();



      //dataSource.addToList(inputStringA, inputStringB);

      String [] data2 = dataSource.getData();
      //data2 = dataSource.insertion(data2);
       // data2 = wordPair.remove(data2);
        listFromFile.setListData(new Object[0]);
        listFromFile.setListData(data2);


    }
  }

  private class WordSelection implements ListSelectionListener
     {
      public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent event)
      {
          int index = listFromFile.getSelectedIndex();
          if (index >= 0)
          {
           String s = wordPair.getWord(index);
           output.setText(s);
          }
      }
     }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JListFromFile jListFromFile = new JListFromFile();
    jListFromFile.setVisible(true);
  }
}

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ListIterator;

/*example of using collection class and input parsing for CIT 271
 *@author Jill Courte
 */

public class SimpleWordList {

 private ArrayList<String> wordListA = new ArrayList<String>();
 private ArrayList<String> wordListB = new ArrayList<String>();
 private ArrayList<String> wordListC = new ArrayList<String>(); 
 private File currentFile = null;
 private WordPair wordPair;
 //words are in the file one word on a line
 //words are read, checked for duplicates, and inserted into the file




 public void createList (File file)
 {
     Scanner fileIn = null;
     currentFile = file;
     String line;

     try
     {
         fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(currentFile.getPath()));
     }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       System.exit(0);
     }


     while (fileIn.hasNextLine())
     {
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        if (! isDuplicate(line))
            insertIntoList(line);
     }

     fileIn.close();
 }

 //Uses an iterator to check for the existance of the given 
 //word in the list
 private boolean isDuplicate (String word)
 {
    Iterator<String> it = wordListA.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        //not ignoring case to look in class at some issues with input
        String s = it.next();
        if (word.equals(s))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
 }

 private void insertIntoList (String word)
 {      
    int index = 0;
    boolean positionFound = false;
    int result;

    while (! positionFound && index < wordListA.size())
    {
        String tmp = wordListA.get(index);

        result = tmp.compareTo(word);
        if (result > 0)
            positionFound = true;
        else
            index++;
    }

    //index holds the position to insert the word

    wordListA.add(index, word);

    //System.out.println(word);
  } 


 public String [] getData ()
    {
        String [] arr = new String[wordListA.size()];

        wordPair = new WordPair();
        String [] temp2 = wordPair.remove(wordListA.toArray(arr));

        // use the collection class method to turn this into a 
        // primitive array
        return temp2;
    }
}




import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
public class WordPair 
{ 
   private ArrayList<String> wordListB;
  private ArrayList<String> wordListC;
  private String [] arrayA;
  private String [] arrayB;  
  private String wordA;
  private String wordB;


   public  String[] remove (String numList[])
   {
     wordListB = new ArrayList<String>();
     wordListC = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
     for( int i=0; i < numList.length; i++)
     {
       String string = numList[i];
       String[] parts = string.split("=");

       wordA = parts[0];
       wordListB.add(wordA);
       wordB = parts[1];
       wordListC.add(wordB);

       }
      System.out.println(wordListC);
     arrayA = wordListB.toArray(new String[wordListB.size()]);

     return arrayA;  

   }

   public String getWord(int index)
   { 
     System.out.println(wordListC);
     return wordListC.get(index);
   } 

}
```

Comment: I may suggest paring all of this code down to just the piece that is causing your issue. Then hookup a debugger and see if you can't isolate the line that is causing your problem.

Comment: I know the WordPair class works correctly bc i tested it in a main method,but when I call it from the simplewordlist class thats where my problem lies I don't have any experience using a debugger so i can't isolate the problem on my own.

Comment: `I don't have any experience using a debugger` - Well now is a great time to start!

Comment: I don't think your wordPair is ever updated with any values after you initialized. Are you sure this same method works for other list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JListFromFile class, you create a WordPair field, wordPair, but you never give it any data that I can see. So it would make sense to me that it would be empty.

Yes, you give a WordPair object data when you call `getData()`, but it's not the same WordPair object that is held by the JListFromFile object. Rather, it's the WordPair object that is held by the SimpleWordList variable, dataSource.

Perhaps you wish to have both objects share the same WordPair object, and if so, this can be done with a little bit of coding:

```
wordPair = new WordPair();     
dataSource = new SimpleWordList(wordPair); // note the parameter
```

elsewhere

```
class SimpleWordList {

   private ArrayList<String> wordListA = new ArrayList<String>();
   private ArrayList<String> wordListB = new ArrayList<String>();
   private ArrayList<String> wordListC = new ArrayList<String>();
   private File currentFile = null;
   private WordPair wordPair;

   // note the assignment constructor
   public SimpleWordList(WordPair wordPair) {
      this.wordPair = wordPair;
   }
```

and elsewhere:

```
public String[] getData() {
  String[] arr = new String[wordListA.size()];

  // ****** don't create a new object -- use the one we have ***
  //  wordPair = new WordPair();  ****** don't create a new one!

  String[] temp2 = wordPair.remove(wordListA.toArray(arr));

  // use the collection class method to turn this into a
  // primitive array
  return temp2;
}
```

Comment: thats what I thought as well.